# CSS not extracted for common chunk with extract-text-webpack-plugin

Tags: webpack-2, bundling-and-minification, extract-text-plugin, commonschunkplugin, extracttextwebpackplugin

Not sure if this is a bug or just my setup, I am using the CommonsChunkPlugin to get a separate common.js for three entry points in my project, and using the extract-text-webpack-plugin to get the css files. My entry points are app, login and register. I am able to get:

```
app.js
app.vendor.js
login.js
register.js
common.js
```

For css:

```
app.css 
register.css
login.css
```

I can't seem to get common.css generated. All the css gets crammed into a single app.css file.

My project is setup based on the vuetify webpack template:
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/webpack-advanced

Here is my config:

3 entry points:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js',
    login: './src/Login/login.js',
    register: './src/Register/register.js'
 },
```

The plugins - I have HtmlWebpackPlugin for each entry point (showing only one):

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  filename: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
    ? 'index.html'
    : config.build.index,
  template: 'index.html',
  inject: false,
  hash: true,
  minify: {
    removeComments: true,
    collapseWhitespace: true,
    removeAttributeQuotes: false,
    minifyJS: true
  },
  chunksSortMode: appChunkOrder
}),
```

Common chunks:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'app.vendor',
  chunks: ['app'],
  minChunks: isVendor,
}),    
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'login.vendor',
  chunks: ['login'],
  minChunks: isVendor,
}),
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'register.vendor',
  chunks: ['register'],
  minChunks: isVendor,
}),    
// Extract chunks common to both app and login
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'common',
  chunks: ['app.vendor', 'login.vendor', 'register.vendor', 'app', 'login', 'register'],
  minChunks: (module, count) => count >= 2 && isVendor(module),
}),
```

The full config:

```
plugins: [
new webpack.DefinePlugin({'process.env': env }),
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  compress: {
    warnings: false
  },
  sourceMap: true
}),
// extract css into its own file
new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].[contenthash].css')
}),
new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
  cssProcessorOptions: {
    safe: true
  }
}),
// generate Html index files for 3 entries:
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  filename: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
    ? 'index.html'
    : config.build.index,
  template: 'index.html',
  inject: false,
  hash: true,
  minify: {
    removeComments: true,
    collapseWhitespace: true,
    removeAttributeQuotes: false,
    minifyJS: true
  },
  chunksSortMode: appChunkOrder
}),
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  filename: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
    ? 'src/Login/login.html'
    : config.build.login,
  template: 'src/Login/login.html',
  inject: false,
  hash: true,
  minify: false,
  chunksSortMode: loginChunkOrder
}),
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  filename: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
    ? 'src/Register/register.html'
    : config.build.register,
  template: 'src/Register/register.html',
  inject: false,
  hash: true,
  minify: false,
  chunksSortMode: registerChunkOrder
}),    
// Chunks:
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'app.vendor',
  chunks: ['app'],
  minChunks: isVendor,
}),    
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'login.vendor',
  chunks: ['login'],
  minChunks: isVendor,
}),
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'register.vendor',
  chunks: ['register'],
  minChunks: isVendor,
}),    
// Extract chunks common to both app and login
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'common',
  chunks: ['app.vendor', 'login.vendor', 'register.vendor', 'app', 'login', 'register'],
  minChunks: (module, count) => count >= 2 && isVendor(module),
}),
// copy custom static assets
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
  {
    from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
    to: config.build.assetsSubDirectory,
    ignore: ['.*']
  }
])
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a very similar setup and managed to get it working. For me, the crucial part was to import common styles in `.js` files instead of in `.scss` files.

Here's my project in a nutshell:

```
common/
  main.scss    <-- common styles
app/
  index.js
  main.scss    <-- styles specific for app
admin/
  index.js
  main.scss    <-- styles specific for admin
registration/
  index.js
  main.scss    <-- styles specific for registration
base.html
webpack.config.js
```

---

`app/index.js`:

```
import '../common/main'   // <-- this did the trick!
import './main'

// some js...
```

Both `admin/index.js` and `registration/index.js` are very similar.

---

`webpack.config.js` (only important parts, using some ES6 syntax):

```
const entries = {
  app: 'app/index.js',
  admin: 'admin/index.js'
  registration: 'registration/index.js',
};

const commonChunks = [
  'vendor',
  'common',
];

function isVendor(module) {
  if (typeof module.context !== 'string') {
    return false;
  }
  return module.context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1;
}

export default {
  entry: {...entries},

  // ...

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'common',
      filename: '[name].bundle.js',
      minChunks: 2
    }),

    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      filename: '[name].bundle.js',
      chunks: [...Object.keys(entries), 'common'],
      minChunks: function(module) {
        return isVendor(module);
      }
    }),

    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: '[name].bundle.css'
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'base.html'),
      filename: 'app.html',
      chunks: [...commonChunks, 'app'],
      chunksSortMode: 'manual'
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'base.html'),
      filename: 'admin.html',
      chunks: [...commonChunks, 'admin'],
      chunksSortMode: 'manual'
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'base.html'),
      filename: 'registration.html',
      chunks: [...commonChunks, 'registration'],
      chunksSortMode: 'manual'
    })
  ]
};
```

---

My initial approach was to import `common/main.scss` in other .scss files, e.g.

`app/main.scss`:

```
@import '../common/main'

// styles specific for app
```

but that didn't work and I came up with the solution above.

Also, adding `chunksSortMode: 'manual'` was required in my case as the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` was sometimes including scripts in the wrong order.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply! I am importing third party packages like: `import Vuetify from 'vuetify'`, I don't know how css files are handled in this case - do I need to import them separately?

Comment: I am hoping the css that comes with third party libraries can be separated out. But I'm not importing them directly by file name...